# Другой сайт копирует (или незаконно воспроизводит) содержимое Stack Exchange. Что следует сделать?

Tags: поддержка, faq

[С момента возникновения](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/now-licensed-under-creative-commons/) Stack Overflow доступ ко всем сообщениям участников сообществ Stack Exchange (т.е. к вашим сообщениям, дорогие друзья) предоставляется на условиях [лицензии CC BY-SA («с обязательным указанием авторства»)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Говоря простым языком, эта лицензия даёт следующие права:

- Любой человек может использовать содержимое Stack Exchange когда угодно без необходимости получения формального разрешения.
- Извлечение прибыли на копируемых сообщениях **полностью** разрешено.
- При этом даже необязательно копировать информацию дословно; исходная публикация становится заготовкой, в которую можно вносить любые изменения.
- Необходимо соблюдать всего два правила:

  - Обязательно указать [**источник**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). Достаточно просто добавить ссылку на исходное сообщение и указать информацию об авторе.
  - Добавить [ссылку на лицензию](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) и разрешить другим людям аналогичным образом использовать новое содержимое при условии соблюдения тех же правил. Как на Мете!

(Если вы захотите освежить в памяти информацию о лицензии, воспользуйтесь ссылкой, расположенной в нижней части на каждой странице сайта.)

Действительно, многие в той или иной степени воспроизводят содержимое наших сайтов по самым разным причинам. К сожалению, при копировании информации со Stack Exchange некоторые лица и сайты не указывают источник надлежащим образом и/или копируют материалы с целью повышения собственного рейтинга.

В данном случае под ненадлежащим указанием источника подразумевается несоответствие нашим правилам при добавлении ссылки на исходное сообщение или при выражении благодарности автору. Бывают вопиющие случаи: я видел сайты, на которых не только не было ссылки на Stack Exchange, но и вообще указывалась ложная информация об авторе и неверная дата публикации — всё для того, чтобы исходные сообщения было *сложнее* найти.

Под повышением собственного рейтинга подразумевается, что сайт, копирующий информацию, оказывается на более высоких позициях в поисковой выдаче, чем аналогичные исходные материалы на Stack Exchange. Это *не всегда* неправильно, но в некоторых случаях может указывать на злоупотребление поисковой оптимизацией.

Итак, вопрос заключается в том, что следует сделать при выявлении случаев незаконного копирования материалов с сайтов сети Stack Exchange.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/</sub>

Comment: А код на гитхаб можно загружать?

Comment: @val Пожалуйста, поясните ваш вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky скажем, копировать код из ответа к себе в код и публиковать на гитхабе/продавать под своей лицензией.

Comment: @val я не юрист, и если вы хотите, чтобы ответ от компании имел юридическую силу, то лучше задать его на [MSE](//meta.stackexchange.com/). Мой ответ в данном случае не несет никакой юридической силы и может быть в корне ошибочным. Из того, как я понимаю лицензию и данную публикацию, речь здесь идет именно о том случае, когда воспроизводится содержимое сайта на другом сайте, подчеркну, именно как содержимое, а не как часть программного кода.

Answer (score 11):

### Что считается «незаконным копированием материалов с сайта» и почему это плохо?

Исторически сложилось так, что на Stack Exchange для обозначения сайтов, осуществляющих незаконное копирование, используется английская аббревиатура SCRAPER (Stack Content Republishers Attributing Poorly and/or Excelling at Ranking — сайты, воспроизводящие содержимое Stack Exchange без надлежащего указания авторства и/или с целью повышения собственного рейтинга). В более широком смысле это любой сайт, копирующий содержимое либо напрямую с веб-страниц, либо с помощью API, либо каким-либо иным образом. В принципе, в таких действиях нет ничего плохого. Материалы Stack Exchange публикуются на условиях лицензии [Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) и могут свободно распространяться при соблюдении [требований по указанию авторства](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) и добавлении ссылки на Stack Exchange в качестве источника. Тем не менее встречаются сайты, которые не соблюдают данные требования при копировании информации или могут вызывать сомнения в благонадёжности по иным причинам.

### В каких случаях следует сообщать о подобных сайтах?

- **Сайт является поддельным.** Какую бы цель ни преследовали подобные сайты, они представляют собой серьёзную угрозу безопасности для нашего сообщества. Иногда они даже появляются в поисковой выдаче Google, и люди переходят по ссылкам, не осознавая, что на самом деле оказались не на Stack Overflow или другом сайте сети. Все это создаёт путаницу, а участники, пытаясь войти на сайт под своей учётной записью, в результате передают конфиденциальные данные стороннему сервису.
- **Сайт не соблюдает требования по указанию авторства.** Часто подобные сайты не прислушиваются к рядовым участникам и отвечают только на официальные запросы от Stack Exchange. Сложности могут возникнуть уже при попытке связаться с администратором сайта. В ряде случаев требуются совсем радикальные меры, которые могут предпринять только представители Stack Exchange. Просим вас сообщать о таких сайтах и указывать, какие именно требования были нарушены.
- **Сайт использует другую лицензию или заявляет права собственности на копируемые материалы.** В соответствии с условиями нашей лицензии любая копируемая информация должна публиковаться на условиях той же лицензии.

### В каких случаях *не нужно* сообщать о подобных сайтах?

- **Сайты соблюдают требования по указанию авторства.** Как указано выше, *нет ничего плохого* в копировании материалов со Stack Exchange на другой сайт при условии соблюдения всех требований по указанию авторства. Если при копировании публикаций все правила соблюдены, ничего делать не нужно.
- **Вы попали на [специальную страницу-заглушку](http://stackexchange.com/about/malware).** Мы уже выявили нескольких подобных сайтов и пресекли их работу, так что теперь при попытке открытия неофициального сайта участник будет перенаправлен на страницу в нашей сети с соответствующим предупреждением. Если *вы считаете, что попали на эту страницу по ошибке* (то есть, по вашему мнению, сайт, который вы пытаетесь открыть, заблокирован по ошибке), воспользуйтесь кнопкой обратной связи на открывшейся странице.

### Каким образом я могу сообщить о подобном сайте?

[Свяжитесь с нами](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) напрямую с помощью специальной формы на сайте. В выпадающем списке выберите пункт «**Содержимое Stack Exchange воспроизведено без указания авторства**» и максимально подробно опишите ситуацию. Даже если сайт полностью состоит из скопированных вопросов, просим указать пример вопроса-копии и соответствующего вопроса на Stack Exchange, а также ключевые слова, поиск по которым в Google привёл вас на этот сайт. Дополнительную информацию вы можете добавить в специальное текстовое поле.

### Какие действия я могу предпринять самостоятельно?

Вмешательство команды Stack Exchange требуется при крупномасштабных нарушениях. Если же человек, скопировавший материалы c сайтов Stack Exchange, просто не знал о необходимости указывать авторство, нам подключаться необязательно. Если вы увидели сообщение в блоге, которое воспроизводит содержимое Stack Exchange, и это единичный случай, вы, как сознательный участник нашего сообщества, можете самостоятельно обратиться к автору блога. Вы вправе указать другому лицу на наши правила и разъяснить требования по указанию авторства в расчёте на то, что автор публикации-копии исправит её.

Если вы обнаружили сайт, имитирующий наше сообщество и содержащий вредоносное ПО, вы также можете направить жалобу на такой сайт напрямую в Google с помощью [формы сообщения о веб-спаме](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport).

Если сайт содержит рекламный код Google AdSense, вы можете [сообщить компании Google о нарушении правил AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/1190500). В других рекламных сетях используются похожие системы подачи жалоб.

### Я являюсь автором сообщения, которое незаконно скопировали.

Если при копировании не были соблюдены требования лицензии CC BY-SA, значит, ваши авторские права были нарушены.

Данное сообщение не содержит юридической рекомендации, как распознать подобные случаи и что при этом следует делать. Дельные советы можно найти на сайтах некоммерческих организаций, воспользовавшись поиском по таким ключевым словам, как *нарушение лицензии*, *лицензионная информация* и *требование соблюдения лицензии*.

- Организация Creative Commons, статья [*«Что произойдёт, если я опубликую свои материалы под лицензией Creative Commons, а кто-то нарушит правила их использования?»*](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-happens-if-i-offer-my-material-under-a-creative-commons-license-and-someone-misuses-them) и статья [«Судебная практика»](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Case_Law).
- Фонд свободного программного обеспечения (Free Software Foundation), статьи [*«Принципы обеспечения соблюдения открытого лицензионного соглашения GNU в сообществах»*](https://fsf.org/licensing/enforcement-principles) и [*«Нарушения открытого лицензионного соглашения GNU»*](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-violation.html).
- Сообщество Wikipedia на разных языках, [шаблон письма с требованием соблюдения лицензии](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4994074).

Comment: @PavelMayorov Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ответ, как считаете правильным. На то он и общий.

Comment: маленькое замечание - SCRAPER - это "бэкроним", расшифровка прежде существовавшего термина как якобы акронима. Ресурсы занимающиеся генерацией контента на основе чужого везде называются так (последнее время добавились  те, что используют нейросеть"). Автопереводы, фальшивые новости или новости из одних заголовков с других сайтов - все восходят к методике желтогазетных "скребков" прошлого... Чисто технически они все существуют в тени закона.